# Change tklabel to file name opened by tkbutton function in R

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am working on creating a widget in R that can open a file and show the characteristics of that file within the same widget. I want this information to be updated automatically when loading the file. This means that I have the following function for the button that can open the file:

```
getfile <- function() {
  name <- tclvalue(tkgetOpenFile(
    filetypes = "{{raster files} {.tiff .tif .img .grd}} {{All files} *}"))

  if (name == "") return;
  Sys.sleep(10)
  assign("Filename", name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  tclvalue(Filename) <- name
}
```

the function for the button that opens this file is:

```
button.widget <- tkbutton(tt, text = "Select File", command = getfile)
  tkgrid(button.widget, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan=3)
```

The label is given by:

```
  Filename <- tclVar("")
  label.widget <- tklabel(tt, text=tclvalue(Filename))
  tkgrid(label.widget, row=2, column=0)
```

However, when I create the widget everything works, Filename is changed and a file can be opened. But the text in the label is not changed. How can i fix this? Is there an event that can be run when I close the OpenFile dialog window?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  tklabel (tt, textvariable=Filename)
```

There is this [example](http://mcu.edu.tw/~chenmh/teaching/project/r/reference/RTclTkExamples/textlabels.html) where he configures the label as text first then reconfigures it with a textvariable.  But you should be able to configure it as a textvariable initially.  Caveat: I don't know R.

The alternative option is to put:

```
  tkconfigure(label.widget,text=tclvalue(Filename))
```

At the end of the getfile() function.

Comment: Correct.  Using (text=variable) on the widget will evaluate only when instantiated; using (textvariable=variable) will cause it to refresh whenever the value of variable changes.  I don't know the R syntax, but I've used Tk from several other languages and this is a constant.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The name is not updated when selecting a file. I assume it is something with R or otherwise I am doing something else wrong. I can post the whole script if you like?

Comment: I've added an alternative method to the answer.  I don't know the scoping rules in R, perhaps there's a variable scoping issue going on?  You also may need to do an 'update' (would it be tkupdate() in R?) to force the display to update if your program continues to run after getting the filename.